# Grails, datepicker, select date and hours/minutes separately

Tags: grails, datepicker

I have a domain class with a date. In a generated view the time for this date (hours, minutes) should be set by the user. For the Date itself I planned a separate selection with a default value (current day). Is this possible with the Grails datepicker?

Here is the code from my view:

```
<g:datePicker name="start" precision="minute"  value="${dailyBookingInstance?.start}"  />
```

Is the calendar-plugin the way to go or can I realise this just with Grails?

Comment: Just use jquery-ui datepicker. You can configure it how u want, and if you want more pretty one, you can use bootstrap datepicker that based on jquery-ui. It'll be the simplest way, for configure it how you can. Or you can rewrote default grails datepicker

Comment: Thanks! I think for hours/minutes I will need smth. like this? http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: yeap<offtop>11 more characters</offtop>